# How to trigger a converter on KeyDown action?

Tags: c#, wpf

My task is to create a converter, that will change an existing expression in `TextBox`. It should work like:

1. We have a non-empty TextBox. |1000|
2. We type some additional:

   - numbers: |1000+5*2|
   - characters: |1000+abc|
3. Now, when the Enter key is pressed, the converter should do its job (change Text in TextBox):

   - numbers (result): |1010|
   - characters (result): |1000+abc|

As you can see, I want to evaluate a numeric expression and do nothing with a mixed one.

For now, my converter works automatically whenever any change in `TextBox` is done.

My converter:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;

namespace TextBoxCalc
{

    public class EvaluateTextBox : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string exp = "";
            bool allow = true;

            foreach (char i in value.ToString())
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(i.ToString(), out int result) || i == '+' || i == '-' || i == '*' || i == '/' || i == '(' || i == ')')
                {
                    exp += i;
                }
                else
                {
                    exp += i;
                    allow = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(exp != null && exp.Length != 0)
            if (exp[0] == '+' || exp[0] == '-' || exp[0] == '*' || exp[0] == '/')
            {
                allow = false;
            }

            if (exp != null && exp.Length != 0)
                if (exp[exp.Length - 1] == '+' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '-' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '*' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '/')
            {
                allow = false;
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (allow)
            {
                var v = dt.Compute(exp, "");
                return v.ToString();
            }

            return exp;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("ConvertBack should never be called");
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxCalc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxCalc"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:TextBoxCalc"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:EvaluateTextBox x:Key="EvaluateTextBox"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="50" Width="200"  Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EvaluateTextBox}, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AcceptsReturn value to true:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EvaluateTextBox}, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Change your converter to check for the newline:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (((string)value).EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
        {
            string exp = "";
            bool allow = true;

            foreach (char i in value.ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()))
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(i.ToString(), out int result) || i == '+' || i == '-' || i == '*' || i == '/' || i == '(' || i == ')')
                {
                    exp += i;
                }
                else
                {
                    exp += i;
                    allow = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (exp != null && exp.Length != 0)
                if (exp[0] == '+' || exp[0] == '-' || exp[0] == '*' || exp[0] == '/')
                {
                    allow = false;
                }

            if (exp != null && exp.Length != 0)
                if (exp[exp.Length - 1] == '+' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '-' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '*' || exp[exp.Length - 1] == '/')
                {
                    allow = false;
                }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (allow)
            {
                var v = dt.Compute(exp, "");
                return v.ToString();
            }

            return exp;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the binding expression, change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to be explicit.
Then in the key down event, check your condition, and add the following lines.

```
BindingExpression binding = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
binding.UpdateSource();
```

Doing this will mean the data binding source is only updated when you press Enter. Since the converter is applied whenever the binding is updated, it too will do it's job only when the button is clicked.

Another way of doing it would be to add a button with the `IsDefault` property set to true, and have the logic in the button's `Click` event handler. The button will be "clicked" whenever you press enter.

Answer (score 0):

As CKII notes, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is the opposite of what you want.

First, we'll move the calculation code into a static helper method. I wasn't sure what your validation was doing so I wrote a quickie for testing. If you're happy with your converter logic, just paste it in.

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static String Calculate(object value)
    {
        return new DataTable().Compute($"{value}", "").ToString();
    }
}
```

We'll get rid of most of the properties you set on the Binding. `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` means "only do this when I call `UpdateSource()` on the binding programatically". I'll use `{RelativeSource Self}` because it makes the XAML easier to copy and paste; I tested this with `ElementName=textbox` with the `x:Name` attribute still on it, and it worked identically.

```
<TextBox
    KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"
    Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Eval}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    />
```

Our keydown event handler will explicitly update the binding on Return only, which will cause the converter to kick in.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        (sender as TextBox)?.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)?.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Finally, you want the conversion in ConvertBack for this to work. I've renamed the converter to EvaluateExpression because it's not tied to TextBoxes in any way.

```
public class EvaluateExpression : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return Helpers.Calculate(value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the same scenario with a viewmodel property and it worked identically:

```
<TextBox
    KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"
    Text="{Binding InputText, Converter={StaticResource EvaluateExpression}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    />
```

You can trivially write an attached property which sets up the update-source-on-return keydown event. That's overkill if you're only doing it once, but if you have multiple textboxes scattered around your application that need to update only on return, it's worth doing.